# Connection from sites using the websocket protocol. Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, websocket, bitcoin

There is a program that connects to the server and receives some data from it + counts server time and signals every 15 or 60 seconds.

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

data = []
count = 0

EM.run {
ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('wss://olymptrade.com/ws2')


ws.on :open do |event|
p [:open]
ws.send('{"uuid":"JCBQ7XBRMYSL0JB4N5","pair":"Bitcoin","size":60}')
end

ws.on :message do |event|
p [:message, event.data]
    data << event.data
    data_servertime = data[0].gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_i
    data.delete_at(0)

    if ((data_servertime % 15) == 0)
        puts "Прошло 15 секунд"
    elsif ((data_servertime % 60) == 0)
        puts "Прошло 60 секунд"
    end
end

ws.on :close do |event|
p [:close, event.code, event.reason]

ws = nil
end

}
```

At startup, it constantly outputs the received data to the console:

```
[:message, "{\"pair\":\"Bitcoin\",\"time\":1516567298,\"open\":11146.938,\"low\":11146.938,\"high\":11146.938,\"close\":11146.938}"]

[:message, "{\"servertime\":1516567298}"]
```

My Questions:

1. How do I put the rest of the data in the array (except for `servertime`) namely: `pair,time,open,low,high,close`?
2. How to make it so that ONLY the information displayed on the screen is displayed, which I intentionally output using the puts command?

Comment: Try to avoid composing JSON manually. You can always do this with [`JSON.dump`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-dump) in Ruby. It's often the case you'll waste hours trying to track down a bug that boils down to a silly missing comma or backslash, something avoided if you let Ruby do it for you.

Comment: your second question is not clear. All the output you show seems to be the result of this line: `p [:message, event.data]`. Do you not consider this to be "intentionally output using the puts command"?

Comment: Sorry. Try to explain more clearly. I have a problem- when i start program a huge amount of system logs display in console. But I don't need this. I want the console display exactly what I wrote (f.e. puts "cat"). Not a huge logs, just the result - cat.